# Integrate an API on a web registration form

Tags: php

I have a website where users can register using their mobile number and the registered user get a text message confirming the registration. The page uses php. The mobile number gets stored as a variable $mobile.

The API for sending sms to the registered user is `http://someurl/&message=[xxxx]&numbers=[xxxxx]`

I want to execute the API in the background. I need to know a way to pass the number stored in $mobile variable to the API's url?

Comment: Use cronjob and file_get_contents() this task

Answer (score 0):

If the remote site responds fast you might try it synchronously: just call something like this:

```
file_get_contents(
  sprintf('http://someurl/&message=%s&numbers=%s',
          urlencode($message), 
          urlencode($mobile)) );
```

But usually it is more safe to perform such tasks independant from processing your registry step. Then you have to store that $mobile number somewhere. Probably you store the users profile data in a database. Also store a flag (marker) that the user has not yet been sent his message.

In addition you configure a cron job to call a script that does nothing but sending overdue messages on the server. It queries the database for any user profile that contains the flag indicating that the message has not yet been send and performs the same command as above.

The advantage: the user gets his feedback of registration right away, even when the sms gateway is down or busy. The message gets send a few seconds or a minute after the registration has completed. Such architecture is usually fast enough and much more stable.

Comment: Thanks alot Arkascha. Its working like a charm :) I need a small help too. I store the users to a database and they have a user id which is stored as $id. I need to include this id in $message. ie, $message should be something like "Your User id is $id". how do I pass the $id to the string?

Comment: The code above does such thing, use the `sprintf()` function again for this: `sprintf("Your User id is '%s'",$id)`. Typically you store the message text in a separate text file, so that it can be changed easily. This is called a 'template', it contains text with a placeholder, a `%s` in this case. Then when constructing the message you read the text files content into a variable $message and apply the `sprintf()` function to it. So something like: `sprintf($message,$id)`. The template could also be stored inside the database, obviously, where is not important as long as it is a separate text.